# For the life of me, I can't figure it out: How do you create a CSS slanted tab menu?

Tags: css, menu, tabs

Something like this:

http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/slanty.html

But...

- The whole entire tab shape should be clickable, including all four corners. In the CSSPlay example, start your mouse at the top-right corner of "Longer Item Three" and move it straight down so that you end by hovering over the bottom-left corner of "Four". As you can see, the top-right corner of "Longer Item Three" doesn't change background color and isn't clickable while the bottom-left corner of "Four" is. The effect I'd want is that either corner should be active/clickable depending on which tab/shape you are hovering on.
  Each tab should be directly adjacent to each other with a grey 1px slanted divider line between each, no white space between
- As little bloat as possible, as semantic as possible. The CSSPlay example has a bunch of  tags that aren't semantic.
- I would want to use a different color gradient image background for each tab, eg. first tab is red gradient, second is blue gradient.
- Needs to be CSS2 to support a greater range of browsers

Does anyone know how? Eternal gratitude and will be yours! Is what I'm asking for possible?

Comment: Without non-semantic code-bloat (to attach `background-images` to, among other things) you **can't**, which is why Stu Nicholls used them in the first place. CSS, and HTML so far as I can tell, only does rectangles, not triangles (or other exotic polygons).

Comment: @David is correct. Of course you can try new CSS3 things, but then that wouldn't fit your requirements.

Comment: @David, I am ok with non-semantic if it's very minimal but his example has like five <b> tags or more for each tab. How about using generic spans instead (why <b>)? Or at least less? I am also open to using JavaScript, just needs to work for IE7/8 at the very least. I was thinking something like an imagemap perhaps? But is that acceptable to use (SEO-friendly) and would it work? What about negative margins to help overlap each other?

Comment: Imagemaps are pretty not-recommended, and negative margins wouldn't make perfect parallelograms. I'd suggest JavaScript, really. As long as it works acceptably without JavaScript, adding a bit of code to make the hover effect perfect isn't a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

When approaching the limits of what's possible with CSS you will encounter lots of trade-offs, and you must chose the trade-offs that best suite your case.

Non rectangular links are only possible with:

- CSS Transforms - only possible on
  CSS3 capable browsers (IE9 Beta;
  Opera, Webkit and Firefox in their
  latest incarnations.
- Image maps - not great for SEO or
  code tidyness/extensibility.
- Lots of extra markup - well, you've
  seen Stu Nichols solution.

Here I've made a quick mock up of a particular solution that I think suits you best:

http://jsfiddle.net/prfez/

[image]

In this particular solution you can't have an image background behind the nav, as the "margins" are a single image sprite that masks the rectangular corners of a gradient.

You also can't apply a hover effect on the background, as the background is applied on the ul instead of the li's.

The advantage is that the html is exactly what you'd expect from a nav.

Please note that the ul gradient background should be replaced with an image background for it to work on IE. And I've only tested on Chrome.

Comment: Works in Firefox, and Safari. Probably in IE if you add CSS3PIE http://css3pie.com/.

Comment: This unfortunately has a trade-off I would consider unacceptable - if you hover over the right slant section of a button, it triggers the next button instead of the current one. Still, +1 for effort.

Comment: @Duopixel, thanks but the top-right corner of the first tab is the click area for the next tab, which is not the effect that is required.  The entire tab, all four corners, need to be contained within the same tab -- my first bullet point (and what thirtydot is saying).  Any way to do this?

Comment: Ok, you're asking for • non rectangular links • IE7 compatible • clean markup. Now, choose two. Here is a second solution that compromises markup in favor of non rectangular links. http://jsfiddle.net/gdDwG/

Comment: I can skimp on clean as long as it works 100% with all 4 corners for the whole shape, and works for IE7/8. My concern was just that the CSSPlay example used so many <b> tags, but if there was a solution that still used a couple non-semantic tags but less than the CSSPlay example, then it would be ok as long as it works. Second solution you have is better than the first but there are still spots where it's not registering for the right tab. If there has to be yet another <span> or something, it would be ok as long as totally works. Can this one be further edited to work? Or a diff solution?

Comment: Yes, it can be refined further with more spans, and (drumroll) the result is CSSPlay's solution.

Comment: Again, there are too many "spans" in that solution.  Would be best to use less and still work right.  Something between yours and CSSPlay's.  But even then, CSSPlay's example doesn't really work 100% anyway -- it also suffers from not having the entire shape register the correct hover or click.  So something between yours and CSSPlay's if it worked right.